# How to print "this is creativeCommon" when the API reply with creativecommon?

Tags: python, json, urllib, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to download some creative commons video using the YouTube Data API, but I'm quite new to this so I'm stuck. How to proceed forward ? I want to find "license": "creativeCommon" in the JSON file and print "this is creativeCommon" I am using python3

```
import json
import re
import urllib.request
from pytube import YouTube

api_key = API_KEY

video_id = "thD8Ad7pWps"
url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id={video_id}&key={api_key}"

json_url = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(json_url.read())

for item in data['items']:
    value = item.get('items')
    print (item.get('license'))
    if value in ['creativeCommon']:
     print ("this is creativeCommon")
    else:
     print ("this is not creativeCommon")
```

The api reply with

```
[{'kind': 'youtube#video', 'etag': '"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/ePPN2XwrH5k8OoNce4d83nQCMZk"', 'id': 'thD8Ad7pWps', 'status': {'uploadStatus': 'processed', 'privacyStatus': 'public', 'license': 'creativeCommon', 'embeddable': True, 'publicStatsViewable': True}}]
```

I expected this to return this is creativeCommon but it returned this is not creativeCommon.

The following is returned :

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-0a69a7438b8f> in <module>
     13 
     14 for item in data['items']:
---> 15     value = data[0]['status']['license']
     16 
     17     if value in ['creativeCommon', 'CREATIVECOMMON']:

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: I don't want to use a library to do this.

Comment: if api reply is what is saved in data, then I do not see any "items". `value = data[0]['status']['license']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change below:

```
value = item.get('items')
```

to

```
value = item['status']['license']
```

This will give you the result: creativeCommon